# What are the limits on using the "no action needed" button in the review queue?

Tags: support, review

Firstly, thank you.  I'd give you a hug if I knew you better.  The review queue finally has a "No Action Needed" button to accompany the "I'm Done".

What's the catch?  I'm assuming that there will be a preset number of times you can click this per day per queue, but are there any other stipulations?

Comment: Looks to me as a button to indicate that "the post is a valid post in its current form and no need of any change". This new feature is good and effective.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no catch.  You can use them as one of your X number of reviews per day (normally 20).  The point is we listened to to your feedback and decided that there are times where a valid action for reviewing a post is "no action".

Comment: I hope you took that as a tongue-in-cheek question and not in an accusatory way, hehe.  Speaking for myself, we do appreciate that the feedback was listened to!

Comment: I did, don't you worry.  Tis the season to be jolly!

Comment: I need fifteen to twenty more upvotes to give to this answer.  **THANK YOU**.

Comment: @Charles Bounty?  Eh? ;)

Comment: It didn't seem to be working for me on Super User just now. I click the button and nothing happened.

Comment: It's possible you have an old cached version of the JS used for the site.  Try clearing history and try again.